# Prevent line break in the extended CV resume

Tags: cv, friggeri-cv

I'm using the [Extended Fancy cv](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/extended-fancy-cv-(carmine-benedetto)) template from Carmine Benedetto additions. 
His example works well until you add some significant lines in the *Experiences* section which will produce a strange line break that put all the experiences text in the next page leaving the 1st page empty. [You can see my example here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/578508622f9062b71caab924) from this code:

```
  \begin{entrylist}
   \entry
    {05/15 - 04/16}
    {Visteon}
    {Ingenieur}
    {Tableau de bord pour la gamme Jaguar LandRover\\}
    \entry
    {07/00 - 07/00}
    {Studiel}
    {Responsable projet}
    {Pistolet de mesure de taux de plomb\\}
   \entry
    {Courant 2014}
    {Packt Publishing}
    {Projet personel}
    {Ecriture et publication d'un livre sur les systèmes embarqués\\}
    \entry
    {07/13 - 08/14}
    {Schneider-Electric / Machine Solutions}
    {Ingénieur développements systèmes}
    {Intégrations de devices pour Somachine et Somachine Basic\\}
     \entry
    {11/10 - 06/13}
    {Stonesoft}
    {Ingénieur développements confirmé}
    {Logiciel SSL/VPN - Logiciel de chiffrement - Audit sécurité de code\\}
   \entry
    {09/09 - 10/10}
    {Orange}
    {Développement Web}
    {développement d’un back-office de modératiion\\}
```

what I want is to keep a line insertion after each *`\entry`* 4th item' whatever the way it's done.

Comment: Simply end an entrylist and start over again.

Comment: That would imply that I should count the entry list items, which I don't want at all as this is a list that will evolve in time. I want Latex to manage this by itself

Comment: It cannot be done with the template. Sorry.

Comment: Most CV templates (all?) are rubbish, as they use tabular environments. And they are a single box.

Comment: Ok, single box, according each people own exp. this box needs to be more or less longer : therefore can be split on different pages

Comment: LaTeX can't break boxes.

Comment: `friggery-cv` (and its forks) is one of the widest distributed design faults.

Comment: ok , got it . Thx. I'm disapointed by that, as this oblige me to count items and produce (a part of) the page layout by myself, which is a feature I thought was nice against WYSIWYGs

Comment: Don't blame LaTeX, it could have done that. Blame the template. ;-)

Comment: OK, no arm to Latex ;) . Unless there are nice-shiny-eyecandy CV template somewhere else ? This is the only one that has a good presentation from the CV templates list

Comment: I think [*awesome-cv*](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) is quite nice to look at, but really really really, i am the wrong guy to ask on template advice. [They confuse me deeply](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/) (follow the link if ou want to know more).

Comment: ah... ok I see this is not a new topic, and you seems to know this well. I'll keep that in mind as I've been working for this fancy template from weeks (python, mako templating and latex) and was about to implement another CV template for an additional CV presentation..... as told in your conclusion : big hope in CV templates

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is the issue solved? How?